# Validate singularity of a string in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, validation

Anyone know if there is anything built into rails to the effect of `validates_signularity_of :string`? I can't find any documentation of anything like this, but just wanted to check. I want to validate that a string the user can enter in is always a singular word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to leverage the `singularize` method.

If singularizing a string results in the same string, the string is already singular.  Otherwise, it is plural.

A custom validator like the following might work:

```
class SingularValidator < ActiveModel::EachValidator
  def validate_each(object, attribute, value)
    unless value.to_s.singularize == value
      object.errors[attribute] << (options[:message] || "is not singular") 
    end
  end
end
```

Then in your model:

```
validates :column_name, :singular => true
```

Credit:
  Basic structure of a custom validator extracted from Ryan's Railscast #211